# Accessing a service in @CanActivate hook

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't figure out a way to access a service and properly configure it's dependencies when that service is accessed from Angular's `@CanActivate` hook.

Before I instantiate a component I need to first check that the user is authenticated. My hook looks like:

```
import {AuthenticationService} from '../authentication/authentication.service';

.................

@CanActivate((next, prev) => {
  var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
    AuthenticationService
  ])

  var authService = injector.get(AuthenticationService);

  return authService.getUser();
})

export class ShellComponent { }
```

The error I get is `EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (AuthenticationService -> Http)`. It should be noted that `HTTP_PROVIDERS` are injected when the application is bootstrapped.

My authentication service is the following:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private _http:Http) {}

  getUser() {
    var resolver = function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function doneCounting() {
            resolve(true);
        }, 5000);
    }

    return new Promise<Boolean>(resolver);
  }
}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In your root component, you may have to specify the `providers` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to add this dependencies to resolveAndCreate, so your code will will be:

```
 var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthenticationService])
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you explain why though, considering I have already injected `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstrapping I though that `HTTP_PROVIDERS` would then be available application-wide?

Comment: Yes, but if you create class instance like this, with Injector, you must provide it in array. Because you inject Http in constructor of AuthenticationService, you must provide it's providers during creation of object.

Comment: I believe since you are creating a new Injector using the static method resolveAndCreate, this injector is not part of the hierarchy of injector that Angular creates when bootstrapping the app and creating component, Hence we need to register the dependency again with the injector.